How to install phantom wallet with 18 word seed phrase generated using sollet wallet?
I uninstalled phantom wallet extension from my laptop which I was using for more than 2 years. I have 18 word seed pharse which generated using sollet wallet. But Phantom wallet accepts only 12 or 24 words.
I could not find any installer for sollet wallet now. so I tried the seed pharse in trust wallet but the address was different, so I could not restore my wallet. please help.
